# TypeScript does not throw error when breaking solid principle

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, solid-principles

In Java when we try to do the following case (polymorphism) it gives us an compile error/exception, which would be expected. but in typescript it doesn't give us an error. why?.

Although we are not extending a class, or rather, an interface and we invoke methods implemented in the following way within a loop sending an array of objects, it normally gives a compilation error (in Java). But in typescript, why not only does it allow compiling, but it runs executing the method even if the object does not belong to the class/interface.
This process of filtering by class/interface is very useful in cases where we apply SOLID principles with all interface things.
Why does this happen in typescript? This is breaking the principle.

```
class Developer {
    drink() {
        console.log(" drink coffee ");
    }
}
class Musician {
    drink() {
        console.log(" drink beer ");
    }
}
class Vintage extends Developer {
    drink() {
        console.log(" drink tea ");
    }
}

class Vegan {
    drink() {
        console.log(" drink water, ??????"); 
    }
}
function queue(processes: Array<Developer & Musician>) {
    processes.forEach(p=>p.drink());
}

let p = [
    new Developer(),
    new Musician(),
    new Vintage(),
    new Vegan(), // Why is this happening?. this does not comply with SOLID.
    new Vegan() // Why is this happening?. this does not comply with SOLID.
]
queue(p);
```

[TypeScript don't throw an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lHLU.png)

I've tested in java all the time, but ... you can see typescript don't throw error properly, I mean a false positive.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: related: [Type systems: nominal vs. structural, explicit vs. implicit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/181154/type-systems-nominal-vs-structural-explicit-vs-implicit)

Answer (score 3):

No, you're not wrong. The issue here is that TypeScript recognizes by-structure rather than by-inheritance. This is called "structual typing."

Answer (score 1):

As @user-id-14900042 said typescript is `structural typing` and you are calling only `drink` method of class. For `TypeScript` just it is important that the `drink` function exists so that your code does not get errors. If you change the name of drink method, It will throw an error:

**Official documentation**

> TypeScript is a Structural Type System. A structural type system means that when comparing types, TypeScript only takes into account the members on the type. This is in contrast to nominal type systems, where you could create two types but could not assign them to each other.

Prone to error code:

```js
class Vegan {
    sayHello() {
        console.log("HelloWorld!"); 
    }
}
function queue(processes: Array<Developer & Musician>) {
    processes.forEach(p=>p.drink()); // throw an error...
}
```